# Specify manual values for scale_*_gradientn with transformed color/fill variable ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a manual scale for the colors in one of my plots. My data span from 0 to 10, and I have quite a few very small numbers. Importantly I want two color gradients. One for points with values < 1, and one for points with values >= 1. Since I have quite a few very small numbers, I want to have the color gradient be on a log scale (diverging at 1).

Simulated data:

```
library(cowplot)
df <- data_frame(xs = rnorm(1000), 
                 ys = rnorm(1000),
                 color_vals =c(runif(500, 0,.001), runif(500, .01,10)))
```

I know I can do this automatically like so (I know it doesn't make sense to have a white point, but this is just a toy example for my more complex map plot):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=xs, y=ys, color=color_vals)) + geom_point() +
       scale_color_gradient2(low="blue", high = "red", mid = "white", trans="log10")
```

[image]

I don't want this type of gradient though, because I want two increasing gradients, split at 1: (1) from grey to blue and (2) from yellow to red.

I know I can specify this with `scale_color_gradientn` this way:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=xs, y=ys, color=color_vals)) + geom_point() +
       scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("grey", "blue", "yellow", "red"),
                             values = scales::rescale(c(0,1,1.000001, max(df$colors))))
```

[image]

but when I try to do this in tandem with the log transform, the gradient doesn't turn out correctly.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=xs, y=ys, color=color_vals)) + geom_point() +
       scale_color_gradientn(trans = "log10",
                             colors = c("grey", "blue", "yellow", "red"),
                             values = scales::rescale(c(0.000001,1,1.000001, max(df$colors))))
```

[image]

The closest I've gotten is to attempt to log-transform the numbers within `rescale`, but that doesn't work properly (though it's close).

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=xs, y=ys, color=color_vals)) + geom_point() +
       scale_color_gradientn(trans = "log10",
                             colors = c("grey", "blue", "yellow", "red"),
                             values = scales::rescale(log10(c(0.000001,1,1.000001, max(df$colors)))))
```

[image]

So how can I specify the correct values for my two gradients if I also want to the gradients to be log transformed?

Comment: What is it that doesn't work properly about the last attempt?  Is it the color bar itself or the colors shown (or both)?

Comment: It's the colors themselves. You can see that some values above 1 are still colored blue. Ideally the blue color would stop at 1, and anything above 1 would be on the yellow to red gradient. The first plot does this, but when I do it on the log scale, it no longer works.

Comment: How does it look if you use the smallest value in the dataset, `min(df$colors)` as your starting point for the log10 scaling instead of .000001?

Comment: Looks the same as the last plot above. I can't figure out why the log transformation makes setting the breakpoint values so difficult

Comment: What is `color_vals` ? You only create a `colors` variable in your data.frame. At the moment, I can not exactly reproduce your plots.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's a typo. The column should be named `color_vals`. I'll edit the post to be accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only specifying the limits for 2 colors, but you have 4 colors. It needs a start and end point for each color. Try the following. You can change the parameters depending on where you want your start/stop points:

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x = xs, y = ys, color = color_vals)) + 
 geom_point() +
 scale_color_gradientn(trans = "log10",
                    colors = c("grey", "blue", "yellow", "red"),
                    values = scales::rescale(log10(
                      c(0, 1, #grey parameters
                        1.000001, 2, #blue parameters
                        2.1, 3, #yellow parameters
                        3.1, max(df$color_vals))))) #red parameters
```

Since you mentioned you'd like to plot only 2 colors, you would delete the two middle value parameters, and delete two of the color options, as follows:

```
  ggplot(df, aes(x = xs, y=ys, color = color_vals)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradientn(trans = "log10",
                    colors = c("blue", "pink"),
                    values = scales::rescale(log10(
                      c(min(df$color_vals), 1,  # <1 (blue) parameters
                        1, max(df$color_vals))))) # >1 (pink) parameters
```

Comment: Yes I think this works, thanks you! In my testing, it seems like you still need the `log10` in between the rescale function and the color values. If that works for you as well, and you change your answers to reflect that I will accept your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey @jesstme, I actually found another stipulation for this. It doesn't seem to work if one of the values within the log10 is 0, because rescale doesn't seem to handle -Inf values well. I had to alter my code to be something like: `min(df$color_vals[df$color_vals!=0]`, instead of `min(df$color_vals)` so that there weren't any 0s included. This wasn't an issue with my reproducible answer, because none of the values were exactly zero, but is an issue in my actual plot. Could you please fix this in both of your examples?